# kubernetes ingress configuration with relative URI in app

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure ingress in a way that allows me to serve several apps under one domain in such way:
`my.domain.com/app1`
`my.domain.com/app2`

Right now I'm trying to use the nginx ingress which is suppose to redirect traffic to `our-nxinx` LB instance and then to the particular app. I did this with ingress config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /demo
            backend:
              serviceName: our-nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

when I access `my.domain.com/demo` I'm landing on
`my.domain.com/login?some_param=1`
which is 404 however, `our-nginx` is getting code 302. I believe this is because our django app underneath uses relative URIs and redirects. I don't want to rewrite the app to make it use absolute URIs. What should be our approach to force the nginx to return correct URL? How should we configure the controller to tell it that appX returns a URL without correct prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` and change path to `/demo(/|$)(.*)`

So it will look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: demo-ingress
  namespace: demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /demo(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: our-nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Tried that as well. It returns the same results. Right now we are a little bit further trying to replace headers and html with nginx filters. But that still needs some tweaking. If we resolve that I will return with an answer.